# A representation of a ball as the intersetion of balls with larger radius

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My question is probably naive but an positive answer would be useful for me. Let $X$ be a separable metric space, $x\in X$, $\delta>0$ and $r_1, r_2,...>\delta$ are given. Is it possible to choose points $x_1,x_2,... \in X$  such that $$\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} B(x_k,r_k)\subset B(x,\delta)\;?$$ (where $B$ stand for a closed balls)
It seems to hold in $\mathbb{R}^d$ but I am not sure if it is true in an arbitrary separable metric space. I would be greatfull for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a counterexample. Let $d$ be the metric on $\Bbb N$ given by $d(n,n)=0$ and $d(m,n)=1$ if $m\ne n$; this metric generates the discrete topology. Since $\Bbb N$ is countable, the space is certainly separable. Note that if $B(n,r)=\{m\in\Bbb N:d(m,n)\le r\}$ is the closed ball of radius $r$, then $B(n,r)=\Bbb N$ if $r\ge 1$, and $B(n,r)=\{n\}$ if $r<1$. Thus, if $\delta=1/2$ and $r_k=1$ for each $k$, there is no way to choose the points $x_k$ so that $\bigcap_kB(x_k,1)=B(0,1/2)$: the lefthand side can only be $\Bbb N$, while the righthand side is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response